# Check if a JTable exists and add rows to it if it does

Tags: java, database, eclipse, swing

I am building an application in Swing where data is being fetched from the DB and populated on the GUI in a JTable.
Before the first run, there is no JTable on the GUI. Once the data is fetched for the first time, the JTable gets created and populated.
First issue:
I need this data to keep refreshing on the JTable.
Second Issue:
In the second run, I want to add a row to the JTable instead of creating a new one. So it should check whether the JTable exists or not and accordingly create a new one or add a row.

Answer (score 1):

You could just always create and add an empty table to the frame.

Then when you execute your code you just check the number of rows in the table:

1. If the number is zero then you create a new TableModel and use the `setModel(...)` method of the table to add the data to the table.
2. If the number of rows is greater than zero then you can use the `addRow(...)` method of your `DefaultTableModel` to add new rows of data.